# Closeness of prime powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For any integer $n$, denote by $pp(n)$ the smallest prime power greater or equal to $n$.

Bound $pp(n)-n$ from above.

Is $pp(n)-n=O(\log n)$, for instance?

Comment: What work have you done so far?

Comment: Allowing only for primes, not prime powers, isn't the answer (on average) _exactly_ $\ln n$ from the prime number theorem?

Comment: I think for primes its O(n^a) with a=0.525. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92599/distribution-of-primes-in-small-intervals It is a much deeper result than PNT I believe. For prime powers a sharper bounds should hold, intuitively speaking.

Comment: Prime powers are totally dominated by primes. Squares and higher powers are rare and won't change a thing. No, I don't expect a sharper bound here.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $pp(n) = P^2$, where $P$ denotes the smallest prime greater than $\sqrt n$. Let $\pi(P) =k$, hence $P \sim k\log k$ where $\pi$ is the prime counting function.Since we have $k> \sqrt n$, we have 
$$pp(n)=P^2 \sim k^2(\log k)^2 > \frac{1}{4}n(\log n)^2 $$

Hence $$ pp(n) -n = O(n(\log n)^2)$$

Notice that the error term $n(\log n)^2$ cannot be improved.

Comment: $pp(6)=7^1$, while $P(6)=3$ and $P(6)^2=9$.

Comment: For any prime p, we have $pp(p^3)=p^3$ so the first line is wrong.